# How to bind DataTable to DataGridView that consists of a DatagridViewTextBoxColumn and a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn?

Tags: binding, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox, datagridviewtextboxcell

I want to ask you a question about my project.

I have a `DataGridView` in my C# project which has two columns: One is `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`, the other is `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

I have ***usernames*** and ***authorities*** columns in my DB. ***Usernames*** are email addresses like ***abc@domain.com*** and ***authorities*** are either **user** or **admin**.

I want to bind via `DataTable` ***usernames*** to `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` and ***authorities*** to `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` but combo boxes must show usernames' authority by default and also have the option to change it between ***user*** and ***admin***.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

you can do all you need in the designer ... you just have to put "user" and "admin" in the Items collection of your DataGridViewComboBoxColumn